# How to remove only bottom border on specified row in html table

Tags: html, css

I have simple html table on which I want to remove bottom border of `tr` on specific row.

The table

```
<table cellpadding="5">
    <thead>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="no-bottom-border">
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
            <td>Test Entry</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I've tried is to add class to the `tr` which I want to be without bottom border `class="no-bottom-border"` and with css to remove it

```
tr .no-bottom-border {border-bottom: none}
```

This doesn't seems to work. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x023t0on/) with the table

Comment: Put tag and class together: `tr.no-bottom-border {border-bottom: none}`

Comment: Thanks but the border is still there.

Comment: Sorry I forgot: `tr.no-bottom-border td {border-bottom: none}` it's the `td` you target not `tr` because `tr` doesn't have borders just `th`,`td`,and `table`

Comment: Tried with `td` and bottom border isn't removed: https://jsfiddle.net/x023t0on/5/

Comment: By default tables collapse their borders, so the top of one cell and the bottom of the cell above it share a border. You need to set the border-collapse property to 'separate' in order to style individual cell borders differently, or individual rows inside a table. Look up the border-collapse documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: It's because it's hardly noticeable everything is grey, try making all borders red and then apply that rule set I gave you at the end of your styles

Comment: @Peter see my answer, sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Target the borders of `td`, because `tr` has no border properties.

### Demo

```css
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #37393b;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  text-shadow: #fff 1px -1px 1px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

table tbody tr td {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #d00;
}

tr.no-bottom-border td {
  border-bottom: none
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
    <tr valign="top">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="no-bottom-border">
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
      <td>Test Entry</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

I copied your code and tried to change it.You just have to remove the border of all td inside .no-bottom-border tr, instead of removing the border of tr.

```
.no-bottom-border td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```